# How can I authenticate through 'local-userpass' in mongodb atlas?

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am following the to-do app sample by referring to the official document of mongodb.
However, the error "E/LoginEvent: Failed to register: [Service] [Unknown(-1)] authentication via 'local-userpass' is unsupported." is **not saved** in atlas.

---

That's why it's stuck in the link here.
[Android With Kotlin Tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/tutorial/kotlin/)

This is the document for the app.
[Template Apps](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/reference/template-apps/)

[image]

Sorry for the lack of explanation. It's my first time learning mongodb, so I don't know how to say it.

I want to follow this tutorial normally, what should I do?

I ask chatgpt and I can't understand even if I keep looking at the official document...
Chatgpt says this behavior is not allowed in the latest version of mongodb, but I don't know exactly.

Comment: It sounds like either the authentication is wrong in the code, or more likely you've not set up the server authentication (correctly). I would suggest going through the [Kotlin SDK Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/install/) first and get comfortable with Realm. Once you've done that, you can add syncing. Other than that, SO is for troubleshooting existing code; when you get stuck, post your code and we'll take a look. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Create User wasn't working for me either. You can create a user in Atlas, if you are using the web then it is under App Services / App Users / Add New User

[image]

You will likely need to make some configuration changes to set up username / password.

Alternatively you can allow anonymous login if you want to have a play around.

```
class TemplateApp: Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    app = App.create(
        AppConfiguration.Builder(getString(R.string.realm_app_id))
            .baseUrl(getString(R.string.realm_base_url))
            .build()
    )
    runBlocking {
        val anonymousCredentials = Credentials.anonymous()
        val user = app.login(anonymousCredentials)
    }
    Log.v(TAG(), "Initialized the App configuration for: ${app.configuration.appId}")
    // If you're getting this app code by cloning the repository at
    // https://github.com/mongodb/template-app-kotlin-todo, 
    // it does not contain the data explorer link. Download the
    // app template from the Atlas UI to view a link to your data.
    Log.v(TAG(),"To see your data in Atlas, follow this link:" + getString(R.string.realm_data_explorer_link))
}
```